# Print a list of values from these functions

Tags: python

Hello so I was wondering how can I 'print' the list of numbers generated by these functions that take the values from the list and squares them. Thanks!!!

```
def square(list):
    return [i ** 2 for i in list]


def square(list):
    return map(lambda x: x ** 2, list)


def square(list):
    for i in list:
        yield i ** 2


def square(list):
    ret = []
    for i in list:
        ret.append(i ** 2)
    return ret
```

Comment: Have you tried using `print`?

Comment: By the way, you should give each function a different name, otherwise at the end you will only be able to use the last one.

Comment: I have tried it but nothing shows, each function is a different way to square a list. My goal in reality is to take 2 lists, add them together and then square root the result. Still trying to work my way on that.

Answer (score 0):

Printing a list by using `print`, for example:

```
print(', '.join(map(str, square([5,3,2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need different function names, or else when you call it, python will only take the last one. 
To answer your question, it is as easy as using a `print` statement. Simply print the return of the function while using a list as the argument.

```
square_list = [1,2,3]
print square(square_list)
```

If you wanted to try a different way, putting the `print` statement in the function also works. 
For example:

```
def square(list):
    print [i ** 2 for i in list] # Instead of return
```

The downside of  this is you cannot store it as a variable or append it to a list later on.

Happy coding!

Comment: @AlanCedeno well, if you wanted to store the return of the function as a variable, you could just say `x = square(square_list)`

Comment: cool, now I have tried the
    def square(list):
        print [i**2 for i in list]
but nothing is showing

Comment: You also have to *call* the function after defining it.

Comment: @AlanCedeno in my first example code, you can see I had to call the function by name and present an argument -- `print square(square_list)` --before the function displays anything.